# Where can I download Oracle Spatial 11g Java API?

Tags: java, oracle11g

I only can find Oracle Database JDBC Java API. But I can't find Oracle Spatial 11g Java API in oracle.com. I tried to google the jar file but it didn't work. Can someone help me?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Oh sorry. But I just have no idea how to get it.

Comment: The 12.1.0.2 version [is available from OTN](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/options/spatialandgraph/downloads/software/index.html). If there is an 11g version and you particularly need that, you might need to get it from Oracle Support.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it! @Alex Poole